# TexStudio: How to use default icon for user command in toolbar?

Tags: texstudio

I defined a user command like this

[image]

And I add it to custom toolbar

[image]

But you see the icon is

[image]

What I want is to use icon of Pdflatex, like that in the "Tools" menu

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Getting the Icon:**

1. The easiest way should be taking a screenshot. As the symbol will be displayed very small, bad quality should not matter that much. Maybe consider removing the background colour with a tool like `gimp` to get a transparent background.
2. Getting it from the source of TeXStudio. Once downloaded the source ball contains a folder `images-ng` where all the icons can be found in `.svgz` format (alternatively it can be found online at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/images-ng/compile-pdf.svgz). Converting it to `.png` can be done e.g. with `inkscape` or google can find you online services to do so.

**Replacing the Icon:**

In the preference menu, you can change the icon simply with a right click.

**Remark:**

Keep the image in the location you selected it from, otherwise you end up with a non existing icon - or in other words an empty space in the toolbar, you can only guess what command it is for.

[image]

Comment: Thank you samcarter. So the default icon is in the source code package, that is why I can't find it.

Comment: @user15964 Well, it has to be somewhere... I just guessed, that it might be easier to find in the source.

Comment: @user15964 There is a folder `images-ng`, with a file `compile-pdf.svgz` which should be the one your are looking for. If you look further perhaps you'll find a png version  of it, otherwise convert it.

Comment: Are you sure there is a folder called imags-ng? I can't find it. Also I can not  find any *.svgz files. I am on windows

Comment: @user15964 Yes, you can also access it online https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/images-ng/compile-pdf.svgz

Comment: @user15964 You're welcome!

Comment: (1) What is the preferred icon image size for the toolbar? (2) Where are the default icons located? *I'm on OSX here, but would be useful to know where they are on various platforms.*

Comment: @gone Comments are maybe not the best place to ask new questions.